# Update ("fill") multiple identical databases ("entity models") with same code in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

OK, I have rouhgly 10-15 (more in the future) SQL Server databases with exactly the same structure. The only difference is the name of the base and from where they are filled. :)

Now I have a different C# project with an entity model for each corresponding DB and each of these projects is filling the DB every hour, 24-7. The question: is there a way to combine all of the projects in a single one, because they contain exactly the same code? If I add 15 entity models in this project, how can I do something like "foreach" entity model?

Hope I explained well, because my English is not so good! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`Entity Framework` connects with database by using `connection string`. If structure of your DBs the same, than yes, you may use one application for all DBs. Just change connection string for each DB

Answer (score 0):

Refering to MikkaRin, you could create your own interface for filling the databases and in the background you use one entity framework. For every insert/update you change your connection string. With this way you have a beatiful interface for working with your data and you can fill multiple database at the same time.

Comment: Hi, can you please give a simple example, 'cuz I'm fairly new to C#.
Let me explain further. :) I'm pulling the data from each client into datatable. With "switch case" I'm using different method for filling different tables in the corresponding DB. Each method is something like this: 
'using (EntityName entities = new EntityName)
 {
   //some code here
 }'
How should I change that?

Comment: I mean, that you build yor own class-model for filling data and the EntityFramework works in the background. So you have a c# interface for your database-handling (all databases at the same time).